# Preparing database to import Facebook languages spoken

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to record 'languages spoken' in my User database and I am planning to import the data from omniauth Facebook login, as well as letting users select which languages they speak themselves when updating their profiles.

I looked up how languages spoken is recorded: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

And it says..

'array of objects containing language id and name'

How can I prepare my Rails database to receive this data? And how can I send data to something like this from the profile form

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the name of the language, then you could simply use a single column called `languages` on the `User` model that's just a comma-separated list of the languages.

If you want more details for each language (e.g. the FB ID associated with it, etc), then you could make a `Language` model that has columns for that information.  Then you could use a `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship for the `User` and `Language` models respectively.

To save to the DB, you'll just need to parse whatever the Facebook API gives you and then save that to the database.